# Build a Keras model that takes a structured array as an input

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm doing Reinforcement Learning to teach agents to accomplish tasks in a 2-dimensional world. A big part of that is to figure out how to represent their environment as neurons.

So far I've represented the world has a 3-d grid of shape (10, 10, 7). The first two 10s are because the size of the grid is 10 in each direction, and the 7 is because I have 7 different kinds of things to say about each space (whether it has food, an enemy, a wall...)

I then used convolutional layers in Keras to process this information and learn from it. It worked and the creatures are [successfully walking towards the food](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzfp3y46276wvrp/VID_20201116_181356.mp4?dl=0).

Now I would like to also add more information that the neural network might figure out how to use. For example, I'd like to encode the last action the agent took. I might also encode the distance or angle to the nearest food. Obviously, this is not 3-d data, this is a sequence of 1-d data.

I want Keras to be able to use that as input together with the 3-d input, and learn from it. I've represented that combined data as a structured array in NumPy:

```
observation = np.zeros((1,), dtype=[('grid', np.float64, (10, 10, 7,)), ('sequential', np.float64, (7,))])
```

That way it's possible to access the grid data as `observation['grid']` and the sequential data as `observation['sequential']`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to get Keras to work with this kind of structured array. My reasoning is that I should build a model using the Functional API, and that model will have two "prongs" for the input that'll connect together to a `concatenate` at some point and get merged to a final output layer.

But, I have no idea how to make Keras figure out that the NumPy structured array should be broken down to the subarrays that it's made of. **Is that possible?**

If I'm going the wrong way with this, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

in keras you can give different inputs as follow

```py
from keras.models import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, concatenate

first_input = Input(shape=(10, 10, 7))
second_input = Input(shape=(7))

c1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same') (first_input)
c1 = Flatten() (c1)
d1 = Dense(10) (second_input)

m = concatenate([c1,d1])
m = Dense(5) (m)

model = Model(inputs=[first_input,second_input], outputs=m)
model.compile(optimizer='adam' loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit([observation['grid'], observation['sequential']], Y_train)
```

this is rough design but it will take your input and concatenate, then produce result